# Selenium web driver with applet

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, applet, sikuli

We have use of applet in web application, this applet is provided by thirdparty to validate user in there database. However, there is a user login and once system validate user, system display text box in applet to enter key code for given text. This key code keep changing and user needs to provide exact key code as sent to there mobile or email. Is there any way to read key code on applet using selenium webdriver and also to send value in field?

This applet is complete code by third party and we do not have any access to their code, we have applet popup when user click on button and user need to enter credential and key code to proceed further..... We are using automation script selenium webdriver with java

Any help would be  really really appreciate.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not able to make any change in the applet, (In case your applet only plays role as a CAPCHA) I strongly recommend you to make a "backdoor" in your code to bypass the keycode. I think it's the only choice you have right now.

If you create a "backdoor", please take a good care at security matters.

Hope help